# Facebook Connect does nothing

Tags: facebook, authentication

have FACEBOOK connect to auto register users on my site - but clicking the "LOG IN WITH FACEBOOK" button does nothing - no pop ups. I've tried various ways of integrating it but still no joy.

Comment: improve your questions by adding some code? maybe your login code and JS

Answer (score 2):

You need to upgrade to oAuth 2.0, Facebook connect has been depreciated. [Facebook Integration for WordPress](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/)